# QFontDatabase doesn't contain all the fonts families or it has different names

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

I'm getting a QWidget's default font's family using font().family(). I compare this against the QStringList I get from QFontDatabase().families(). The default font's family is "Sans" but I cannot find that in the list I get from QFontDatabase, I can only find Sans Serif, Droid Sans, FreeSans etc. How come QWidget's default font is something that is not even present on the system's fonts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic trip-up.

Logically, `QFont` is a *request* for a font. It may be satisfied by something that doesn't quite match what was requested. The *actual font* is available from `QFontInfo`.

If you think about it, you can put "whatever" in a `QFont`. At what point should `QFont` change itself to indicate what font was actually selected? It'd be rather baffling if you set a font on a widget, then read it back, and it got changed to match what fonts are there. So, there's no such reasonable point where a `QFont` could morph, so `QFont` can't be but a request.

You control `QFont`, but the system's font availability and other constraints controls the matching `QFontInfo`.

The invariant may be expressed as:

```
QFontDatabase db;
QFont const font = widget->font();
QStringList const families = db.families();
Q_ASSERT(families.contains(font.family()) || true);
QFontInfo const info(font);
Q_ASSERT(families.contains(info.family()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sans` is a family alias.

`Droid Sans` is a font family name.

QFont("Sans") returns a font with family "Sans" and closest params for your request (.boldness, size, lang, script, features, etc)